# How to execute shell commands in pig script on amazon Elastic Map Reduce?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, apache-pig, elastic-map-reduce

By using bootstrap i was moving some source files to master node. While creating the jobflow through elastic-mapreduce-client, I will pass a pig script, that will launch embedded python from the source files that present in master node.

following commands i have used to create the jobflow,

```
./elastic-mapreduce --create --alive --name "AutoTest" \
--instance-group master --instance-type m1.small \
--instance-count 1 --bid-price 0.20 \
--instance-group core --instance-type m1.small \
--instance-count 2 --bid-price 0.20 \
--log-uri s3n://test/logs \
--bootstrap-action "s3://test/bootstrap-actions/download.sh" \
--pig-script \
--args s3://test/rollups.pig
```

rollups.pig contains the following code that launches the embedded pig file,

```
sh pig automate.py
```

If i run the rollups.pig in local machine, it will fire the automate.py successfully. but when i try to run this by using amazon elastic map reduce, it is not working ?